# Changing save or put functions in database orms

Tags: database, django, google-app-engine, orm

I've noticed something when dealing with databases, especially python ORMs that deal with databases.

Here is an example of a `save()` function in django:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.somevar = dosomething(self.someothervar)
    return super(<Your_Model_Here>, self).save()
```

Also in google app engine, where the function `put()` is used:

```
def put(self, **kwargs):
    self.<some_var> = doSomething(self.someOtherVar)
    return super(<Entity>, self).save()
```

Now, I understand why we do this, IIRC, we do this because we are not manually writing the `put()` or `save()` function, so we need to use the super call for this to function properly.

Could someone please give me a more detailed explanation as to why save functions are like this. My understanding of it is wrong, because I learned by just going in and coding, but I really do not (clearly) understand what is going on when I write a `save()` or `put()` function.

Comment: This is how inheritance works in Python. Perhaps you are coming from other languages where the parent class constructor is called automatically; in Python you have to call it explicitly.

Comment: No, I understand how this is working, just I don't understand the part where we put in the subclass into the super call, we're just type casting it then?

Comment: Python has multiple inheritance, so the `super` function has to check the ancestors to see what method should be called (there is a predefined order called "diamond pattern" in which the ancestors will be looked upon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just witnessing a method being overridden in a subclass. The purpose of subclassing is to reuse code and override functionality as necessary. Sometimes, that involves overriding a method and calling pieces of its parent.

`super` calls the parent class's method.

This is exactly the same as doing no subclassing at all:

```
def save(...):
   return super(MyClass, self).save(...)
```

Conversely, if we just wrote a method without a super call, it would *replace* the parent class method functionality completely.

```
def save(...):
   print ("I have nothing to do with my parent class")
```

If we want to supplement functionality (i.e. keep the old behavior but add something extra in) we use super to call the original method from within the new method.

```
def save(...):
   print ("I am called directly before the original parent method")
   return super(MyClass, self).save(...)
```

Comment: Okay, but we are passing in the Class as a parameter, how does `super` know how to manager that?

Comment: A Class is subclassed, a method is overridden.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, but the intricacies of super are beyond my skill and the official docs point to this by Raymond: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: I read the article, and the example the person gives are clear, you can see that by `super().__setitem(key, value)`, here you are just using the super-class to set the item. What I do not understand is how can the `super()` class itself take a parameter? As in, if you type-cast it as the super-class, then are you not losing the data that you just stored in the new sub-class? What I mean by a parameter is `super(subclass, self)` <- what is going on here? I mean, I get what I am doing, but it just does not make sense. I'm sorry if I sound really stupid here, I'm struggling.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: I guess the Python core developers asked the same thing, that is why super don't need parameters anymore in Python 3. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, the multiple inheritance resolution stuff is confusing to me but I don't see why a parent method can't be called with the child instance passed in as the self `SomeParentClass.some_parent_method.__func__(my_child_instance)`

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: It can be, but it should lose some data, should it not, since you're type-casting the subclass as a super-class?

Comment: The use of super in the examples means you can change the parent class without having to change the code.  You can call SomePArentClass.some_method(obj_self) however if you change your parent class, then you have to remember to change the explicit call.